# Контекст вызова функции

Tags: javascript

Почему в данном коде `this` у `window.setTimeout` в одном случае - это объект `a1`, а в другом - `window`? Ведь должен быть `window` в обоих случаях: контекст выполнения `window.setTimeout` (она же вложена в метод, но сама - не метод объекта `a1`)?

```js
var a1 = {
    petalCount: 7,
    declare: function() {
        console.log('Я прекрасный цветок с ' + this.petalCount + ' лепестками!');
    },

    bloom: function() {
        console.log("====вот this в bloom========");
        console.log(this);

        window.setTimeout(this.declare(this), 1000); //this этой функции - это  объект a1 
        window.setTimeout(global, 1000); //this этой функции - это window
    }
    // а надо было бы вот так делать (так тоже работает):
    //   bloom : function() {
    //   var self =this;
    //  window.setTimeout(self.declare(self), 1000);       
}

a1.bloom();

function global() {
    console.log("а я в контексте выполнения Window");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

По поводу непосредственно вопроса и  `window.setTimeout(this.declare(this), 1000);`: в `setTimeout` попадает результат вызова `this.declare(this)`.

Убедиться в этом можно в [этом примере](http://jsfiddle.net/wjbetfd3/) - внутри функции с `console.log('timeout');` `this` указывает на `window`.

---

А если в целом:

Если сильно вкратце, то `this.declare(this)` вызывается для (в контексте) `this` (который в данном случае`a1`). Внутри функции `this` указывает на тот объект, для которого вызван метод - опять-таки на `a1`.

Во втором же случае вызов такой: `window.global` - внутри функции `this` указывает на `window`.

Первый случай можно расписать как `window.a1.declare.apply(window.a1, window.a1);`, второй - как `window.global.apply(window);`

---

Пример с правильным вызовом `declare` после задержки (здесь `var self = this` действительно пригодится):

```js
var a1 = {
    petalCount: 7,
    declare: function() {
        console.log('Я прекрасный цветок с ' + this.petalCount + ' лепестками!');
    },

    bloom: function() {
        console.log("====вот this в bloom========");
        console.log(this);
        
        var self = this;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            self.declare(self);
        }, 3000);
        window.setTimeout(global, 1000);  
    }
}

a1.bloom();

function global() {
    console.log("а я в контексте выполнения Window");
}
```